# How to enable chromedriver logging in from the selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I enable the chromedriver verbose logging capabilities from within the selenium webdriver?

I found the appropriate methods `loggingTo` and `enableVerboseLogging` but cannot seem to use them prtoperly:

```
require('chromedriver');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

let capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setScrollBehavior(1);
let builder = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities);
builder.enableVerboseLogging(); // fails!!!
let driver = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comment of [chrome.js](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js), there is a way to enable logging for chromewebdriver

```
 *
 * By default, every Chrome session will use a single driver service, which is
 * started the first time a {@link Driver} instance is created and terminated
 * when this process exits. The default service will inherit its environment
 * from the current process and direct all output to /dev/null. You may obtain
 * a handle to this default service using
 * {@link #getDefaultService getDefaultService()} and change its configuration
 * with {@link #setDefaultService setDefaultService()}.
 *
 * You may also create a {@link Driver} with its own driver service. This is
 * useful if you need to capture the server's log output for a specific session:
 *
 *     let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
 *
 *     let service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder()
 *         .loggingTo('/my/log/file.txt')
 *         .enableVerboseLogging()
 *         .build();
 *
 *     let options = new chrome.Options();
 *     // configure browser options ...
 *
 *     let driver = chrome.Driver.createSession(options, service);
 *
```

Also you have other option:

- Running ChromeDriver as a standalone process

Since the ChromeDriver implements the wire protocol, it is fully compatible with any RemoteWebDriver client. Simply start up the ChromeDriver executable (that works as a server) with arguments `--log-path` and `--verbose`, create a client, and away you go:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
  "http://localhost:9515",
  DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: For any looking for c# version of this... `var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
                service.LogPath = Path.Combine("c:\path\to\where\you\want", "chromedriver.log");
                return new ChromeDriver(service, options);`