# Why caret symbol "^" doesn't work with Java+Selenium+Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, unicode, sendkeys

I'm trying to write a password with letters and special characters but the character caret "^" doesn't work. I tried to add \^ (because I'm testing with Java) after the `sendKeys`, wrote the unicode, etc.

Other characters like "`" are working fine. But this is not working

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("\\^"); 
webDriver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("ExA^mplePass1");
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Have the same issue in C#, started happening a couple of weeks ago - a test working for years started failing. Upgraded selenium and chrome driver - no joy. I debugged, and definitely webElement.SendKeys("^") just gets ignored.

Comment: Update - I ran it with selenium FirefoxDriver and it worked, so it's probably something with ChromeDriver.

Comment: Same issue here: Even escape sequence (``.SendKeys("\u005E")``) gets ignored. Seems to be a language/keyboard layout problem. What does `.SendKeys(Keys.Shift + "6")` print for you? It is supposed to print `^` using US keyboard layout which I believe Selenium/ChromeDriver should use by default. Do you have the US keyboard layout installed on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I could confirm my suspicion: ChromeDriver is configured to always use keyboard layout `US - QWERTY`. If it is not found, some other, very basic layout is used which does not include special characters like `^` or `°`. Consequence: Special characters are just not printed, no matter what you pass to `SendKeys()`.

This behavior is actually [by design](https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/blob/220b02e6c465a9cddc24af97f236dd0eecd8e28b/chrome_launcher.cc#L475) and even [well documented](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/help/keyboard-support). An informational log entry mentions the problem if one actually [enables logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803545/how-to-enable-chromedriver-logging-in-from-the-selenium-webdriver):

> Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted
>   incorrectly

The solution is to install keyboard layout `US - QWERTY` (code 00000409) (not `US International - QWERTY` or anything similar). It does not matter for which language you add this layout.

Go to Windows "Language settings", click any language under section "Preferred languages" and chose "Options". Then add `US - QWERTY`:

[image]